# Can you speed up this algorithm? C# / C++

Tags: c#, c++, string, algorithm

Hey I've been working on something from time to time and it has become relatively large now (and slow). However I managed to pinpoint the bottleneck after close up measuring of performance in function of time.

Say I want to "permute" the string "ABC". What I mean by "permute" is not quite a permutation but rather a continuous substring set following this pattern:

```
A
AB
ABC

B
BC

C
```

I have to check for every substring if it is contained within another string S2 so I've done some quick'n dirty literal implementation as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= strlen1; i++)
{
   for (int j = 0; j <= strlen2- i; j++)
   {
      sub = str1.Substring(i, j);
      if (str2.Contains(sub)) {do stuff}
      else break;
```

This was very slow initially but once I realised that if the first part doesnt exist, there is no need to check for the subsequent ones meaning that if sub isn't contained within str2, i can call break on the inner loop.

Ok this gave blazing fast results but calculating my algorithm complexity I realised that in worst case this will be N^4 ? I forgot that str.contains() and str.substr() both have their own complexities (N or N^2 I forgot which).

The fact that I have a huge amount of calls on those inside a 2nd for loop makes it perform rather.. well N^4 ~ said enough.

However I calculated the average run-time of this both mathematically using probability theory to evaluate the probability of growth of the substring in a pool of randomly generated strings (this was my base line) measuring when the probability became > 0.5 (50%)

This showed an exponential relationship between the number of different characters and the string length (roughly) which means that in the scenarios I use my algorithm the length of string1 wont (most probably) never exceed 7

Thus the average complexity would be ~O(N * M) where N is string length1 and M is string length 2. Due to the fact that I've tested N in function of constant M, I've gotten linear growth ~O(N) (not bad opposing to the N^4 eh?)

I did time testing and plotted a graph which showed nearly perfect linear growth so I got my actual results matching my mathematical predictions (yay!)

However, this was NOT taking into account the cost of string.contains() and string.substring() which made me wonder if this could be optimized even further?

I've been also thinking of making this in C++ because I need rather low-level stuff? What do you guys think? I have put a great time into analysing this hope I've elaborated everything clear enough :)!

Comment: [Longest common substring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem) can be found in linear time.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, I wasn't trying to "optimize" string contains or substring per-se but rather do this in a different way to avoid calling those so often

Comment: You want to find out whether two strings have a common substring, do you not? There are algorithms that can do that in `O(N+M)` time. Is this not what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks for your post I've misunderstood the wiki page this might be what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: If you are going with the C++ iterator approach instead of a common-substring algorithm, you could perhaps speed up the search by looking for the longer substrings first, which may save you subsequent searches: If "ABC" is contained, all other subsequences are also contained; if "BC" is contained, "B" and "C" are contained.

Comment: I haven't thought of that, thanks both of you!

Comment: @IgorTandetnik : while it seems that searching for the longest common substring includes discovering all, are you sure about `in linear time`? Linear in _what_?

Comment: @greybeard Linear in the total length of inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is tagged both C++ and C#.

In C++ the optimal solution will be to use iterators, and `std::search`. The original strings remains unmodified, and no intermediate objects get created. There won't be an equivalent of your Substring() taking place at all, so this eliminates that part of the overhead.

This should achieve the theoretically-best performance: brute force search, testing all permutations, with no intermediate object construction or destruction, other than the iterators themselves, which simply replace your two `int` index variables. I can't think of any faster way of implementing this basic algorithm.

Comment: The post had gotten many downvotes, not sure why maybe I created a confusion tagging both C++ and C#? What I wanted to say is if it would speed up by a worthy-amount to rewrite this in C++ ?

You're right I think this would speed things up surely. You forget about iterators and such once you spend too much time with C# hehe, Thanks! @Sam Varshavchik

Answer (score 1):

Are You testing one string against one string? If You test bunch of strings against another bunch of strings, it is a whole different story. Even if You have the best algorithm for comparing one string against another `O(X)`, it does not mean repeating it M*N times You would get the best algorithm for processing M strings against N.

When I made something simmiliar, I built dictionary of all substrings of all N strings

```
Dictionary<string, List<int>>
```

The `string` is a substring and `int` is index of string that contains that substring. Then I tested all substrings of all M strings against it. The speed was suddenly not `O(M*N*X)`, but `O(max(M,N)*S)`, where S is number of substrings of one string. Depending on M, N, X, S that may be faster. I do not say the dictionary of substrings is the best approach, I just want to point out that You should always try to see the whole picture.

Comment: When I tested my program I created an array of 100 items with length of M containing random letters in ascii range ('a' to 'z'). Then I've looped through the generated array of random strings and randomly generated a input string of length (i) and measured the time taken for this 100 comparisons to process.. Then I've done i++ checked for a newly random generated input string of length 2 against a newly random generated array of 100 random strings again of the same length M